# Table of Contents - How to add the "Chapter" label

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, appendices, appendix

In the `Table of Contents` I get only the `numbers`, but I also want to have the `prefix`.
How can I add the word "`Chapter`" before the number in each chapter title in the Table of Contents?

It currently looks like this:

```
Contents
1 Introduction
2 Microbiology
3 Electric Properties
```

I want it to look like this:

```
Contents
Chapter 1: Introduction
Chapter 2: Microbiology
Chapter 3: Electric Properties
```

The code in the `main.tex` is the following (I also have 3 other `.tex` files, named `Chapter_1`, `Chapte_2` and `Chapter_3` respectively that I call in the main):

```
\documentclass[twoside, a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}
 
\usepackage[top=2.5cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, headheight=1.25cm, footskip=1.25cm, margin=1in]{geometry}
 
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\usepackage{appendix}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}{Chapter~\thesection :}{1em}{}

\usepackage{tocbasic}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  entrynumberformat=\entrynumberwithprefix{\figurename},
  dynnumwidth,
  numsep=1em
]{tocline}{figure}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  entrynumberformat=\entrynumberwithprefix{\tablename},
  dynnumwidth,
  numsep=1em
]{tocline}{table}
\newcommand\entrynumberwithprefix[2]{#1\enspace#2:\hfill}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=black,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,      
    urlcolor=black,
    }
\urlstyle{same}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\section{Introduction}
\input{Chapter_1}
\clearpage

\section{Microbiology}
\input{Chapter_2}
\clearpage

\section{Electric Properties}
\input{Chapter_3}
\clearpage

\appendix
\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{APPENDIX A:}{1em}{}

\section{FIRST EXAMPLE OF APPENDIX}

\end{document}
```

`P.S. 1:` I use `XeLaTeX` as a compiler and `Overleaf` as an editor.

`P.S. 2:` I only included `tocbasic` in order for you to see how I use it for inserting the label of tables and figures in the Table of Contents.

`P.S. 3:` I also included `hyperref`, etc. in order for you to see what is the basic structure of the real document, you have to excuse me if this was a mistake.

`P.S. 4:` I want the same for the `appendices`, but I assume it will be the same command with different variable.

`P.S. 5:` General question. Do you know if it is more correct to have "Contents" or "Table of Contents" as a name for the Table of Contents? Because I have seen both many times and I don't know what to use. For a thesis or a book.

Comment: `article` does not provide chapters, only sections and subdivisions of section. Using `\clearpage` before each `\section` is also nonsense. In combination of both `report` would IMHO be more suitable. Your example **once again** is not working. Unfortunately instead of correcting your question, you've once again deleted the old one and posted a new one. So you've lost the links about how to make correct minimal working examples and also other useful notes. This is very contra productive and annoying. So I will not waste time for one more speculative answer.

Comment: Please edit your previous version of this question instead of asking it again. If you keep deleting your downvoted question instead fixing their problems, you'll risk running into a question ban.

Comment: @cabohah For God's sake! Could you be more calm with me please? StackOverflow appeared a message telling me to delete it because it could not longer accept answers. That is why! Also, I am writing a thesis, what am I supposed to have instead of article? I have onyl  2 weeks using LaTeX and I am not a programmer. Also why \clearpage is nonsense? I want it to change page every time I have a new chapter.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I didn't know that you would be able to answer it again... Sorry. It said either delete or edit but you woudln't be able to answer it.

Comment: @DGuys Once you fixed all the problems in your previous question, you can undelete it and if people deem it clear enough, they will vote to reopen it in the review queue.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Okey, I will know it from now on! But i deleted the previous one, so could we please do this process here?

Comment: You simply don't want `\section` but `\chapter` and therefore don't want `article` but either `report` or `book` and then something like [the answers to this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/392235/277964). Alternatively you could use a more configurable class like `memoir` or `scrreprt` or `scrbook`.

Comment: @cabohah 1) What do you recommend more suitable for a thesis? 2) So I will just change \section with \chapter and all the other characteristics should remain the same? And if I understood correct I will have \section and subdivisions of section inside a \chapter?

Comment: Thesis or not is not so important. You want chapters, that start on a new page. So `article` is not suitable, but `report` or `book` would be (or `memoir` or `scrreprt` or `scrbook` or another class providing chapters). You want changes for the chapter headings of the standard classes. So you either need a package like `titlesec` or use a more configurable class like `memoir`, `scrreprt` or `scrbook`. You need changes to the table of contents. So you either need a package like `tocbasic`, `tocloft` etc. or a more configurable class like `memoir`, `scrreprt` or `scrbook`.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: You are already using the KOMA-Script package `tocbasic`. So maybe using `scrreprt` or `scrbook` would be a suggestion, because these are also using `tocbasic`. But in this case, you should replace `titlesec` by the interface of `scrreprt` (resp. `scrbook`). With `memoir` you also should not use `titlesec` nor `tocbasic` but use the `memoir` interface. I cannot tell you what would be *best for your*, because I don't know all your needs nor your *taste*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO you want something like:

```latex
\documentclass[numbers=noenddot,listof=totoc]{scrbook}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}% instead of \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}
 
\usepackage[top=2.5cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, headheight=1.25cm, footskip=1.25cm, margin=1in]{geometry}
 
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{newtxmath,newtxtext}% instead of
                                % \usepackage{fontspec}\setmainfont{Times New
                                % Roman}

\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{\chapapp~\thechapter:\enskip}
\renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{\chapapp~\thechapter:\enskip}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  entrynumberformat=\entrynumberwithprefix{\figurename},
  dynnumwidth,
  numsep=1em
]{default}{figure}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  entrynumberformat=\entrynumberwithprefix{\tablename},
  dynnumwidth,
  numsep=1em
]{default}{table}
\newcommand\entrynumberwithprefix[2]{#1\enspace#2:\hfill}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  tocentrynumberformat=\entrynumberwithprefix{\chapapp},
  tocdynnumwidth,
  tocnumsep=1em,
  beforeskip=0pt,
  afterindent=false,
]{chapter}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=black,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,      
    urlcolor=black,
    }
\urlstyle{same}

\usepackage{mwe}% for dummy text, images etc.

\AddToHook{cmd/appendix/after}{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\string\def\string\chapapp{\chapapp}}%
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\blinddocument

\appendix

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

[image]

BTW: Using a KOMA-Script class instead of a standard class also opens an alternative for the number prefix in the List of Figures and List of Tables. Instead of

```latex
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  entrynumberformat=\entrynumberwithprefix{\figurename},
  dynnumwidth,
  numsep=1em
]{default}{figure}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  entrynumberformat=\entrynumberwithprefix{\tablename},
  dynnumwidth,
  numsep=1em
]{default}{table}
```

you can add class option `listof=entryprefix`. This already activates the “Figure” and “Table” before then numbers. To additionally have a “:” after the number, you can use these two lines in the document preamble.

```latex
\BeforeStartingTOC[lof]{\let\autodot:}
\BeforeStartingTOC[lot]{\let\autodot:}
```

For more information about the used class options and about changing the chapter headings and chapter entry to the ToC using `\RedeclareSectionCommand` or to change the page header and footer (using class options or KOMA-Script package `scrlayer-scrpage`) see the English or German [KOMA-Script](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) manual.

An alternative would be to use `scrreprt` with option `twoside` instead of `scrbook`. With `scrbook` additional option `open=any` could be interesting. Several other features of `scrbook` and `scrreprt` could also be useful. So reading the manual — not the whole at once but a few pages each day and whenever you need an additional feature — would be recommended.

For detailed question about how to change things using a KOMA-Script class and the KOMA-Script package, see the several [KOMA-Script questions and answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/koma-script) (and also the manuals) or ask *new* questions with suitable minimal *working* examples.